# Why does adding a wifi hotspot connection prevent my VPN working when normal wifi works fine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, routing

When I connect to my normal wifi connection from home, it's the 192.168, everything works fine with my VPN and adding the extra route I need for the 10.0.0.0 address with this command:

route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 gw 10.100.1.99

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlo1
10.0.0.0        10.100.1.99     255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.100.1.99     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0                0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlo1
```

But when I connect with my wifi hotspot device (yourkarma.com) it adds:

169.x.x.x

address to wlo1 above the 192.168 one and then nothing works over the VPN.

Any idea how to get VPN to work via the wifi hotspot when the 169 ip is in the route -n list?

Here is full history:

```
route -n

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlo1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlo1

echo "c myvpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlo1
10.100.1.99     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlo1

# at this point if I do route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 gw 10.100.1.99
# i would get this new route and ssh to ips inside my vpn would work
# 10.0.0.0        10.100.1.99     255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 ppp0
#
# but to show the problem instead of adding that route, I swtich over to karma wifi

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlo1
10.100.1.99     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlo1

# notice the new 169.254.0.0 with that 255.255.0.0 Genmask show up. When I try and
# add the route for 10.0.0.0/8 I get:

SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: If your computer is getting a 169.254.x.x address, it is because it can't get an IP from a DHCP server. This is a default configuration to help computers trying to talk on the same network communicate with just a switch. I'm guessing your hotspot is setup incorrectly or isn't getting a connection, and therefore your computer is not getting a usable IP address, causing your issues.

Comment: well the normal internet still works. it's *just* the vpn that no longer works.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. VPNs (depending on the kin/setup) will add themselves as network adaptors (NIC cards) that just tunnel all of their traffic to the end point, sort of like an ethernet connection between your computer and the remote network. So it sounds like either your client is configured oddly or there is some DHCP/IP issue on the remote network, because when you connect, something is supposed to give you an IP on that network. Does anyone else have this issue? If this is a corporate VPN, there might be some white list or permission setup.